# exception-notification gem "ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, rubygems

Been using the `exception-notification` gem for some time now rather successfully, however I have been annoyed by an entry in the emails at the top of each email body just after the actual error.  The problem text is:

```
-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary:

 ActionView::Template::Error: Missing rack.input
```

The next few lines are even always the same.  What does this indicate?  How do I resolve the issue so that I no longer see this error before anything meaningful rises to the top of the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that ExceptionNotifier is encountering a problem when generating [this file](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/blob/master/lib/exception_notifier/views/exception_notifier/_request.text.erb). This generally happens when you've customized the data being sent to it. Can you add your middleware config* to the question so we can see if that's the problem? Additionally, can you confirm what version of Rails & exception-notification you are using, and if you are setting any custom data** in your request env?

*** it should look like this

```
Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
  :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
  :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@example.com}
```

** something like this in a before filter

```
request.env["exception_notifier.exception_data"] = { ... }
```